# Load my own R package

Tags: r

I made an R package for personal use, but the way I load it is by individual files. Such as:

```
source("../compr/R/compr.R")
source("../compr/R/error_df.R")
source("../compr/R/rmse.R")
```

I would like to load the entire package, which is called `compr`, as I would other libraries.

Comment: Have you tried if this provides enough information for your case? https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RStudio, I would suggest creating a project and setting it to your `compr` directory. After that you will be able to use `devtools::load_all()` to load your package directly.

If you don't want to do this, or you don't use RStudio `devtools::load_all('path/to/compr')` will also work.

P.S. `compr` directory needs to be the root of the package i.e. the place where your DESCRIPTION file is.